# DNS lookup events stopped propagating to log analytics

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace, azure-agent

everyone.
We faced with the next situation, suddenly our dns lookup events logs stopped propagating to log analytics.

We are using old MMA agent, I see that dns server is set up properly, it resolves the names and dig command receives correct ip.

I see dns lookup events logs event viewer, but lookup logs are not sent to Azure VM logs.
VM is connected to log analytics workspace and in mma agent everything looks good:
[image]

We created the list of hosts using powershell and the configuration change events are propagated correctly.

Another VM with pretty same config works fine.
What are we missing?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: The questions you answer tend to be about MS Azure configuration, pricing, infrastructure, and other cloud-related issues, instead of being practical programming problems. StackOverflow is meant to discuss only programming questions. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
for more details. Please post your non-programming question on other platforms such as [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)
, and [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/tags/133/azure)
for immediate help. Thanks!